# :focus pseudo class with next sibling curiosity

Tags: css

I know people here tend to read the draft specifications, but unfortunately i lag in that department so i have a question.

Is this a bug, not implemented yet, will not be implemented or not known yet?

```
<div>Hello there</div>
<div>I'm next</div>

div:hover + div { background: blue; } /*works*/
div:focus + div { background: blue; } /*does NOT work*/
```

EDIT: this div structure choice is a bad example because it's quite hard to focus the div in an environment like the jsfiddle, but still, general question.

EDIT2: Scratch that, it works, but you can't focus it with a mouse. Weird.

EDIT3: You actually can, see accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default element is passive - is not getting focus.

To make element focusable it should be either `<input>` or has `tabindex` attribute:

Try this:

```css
div:hover + div { background: blue; } 
div:focus + div { background: red; }
```

```html
<div tabindex="1">Hello there</div>
<div>I'm next</div>
```

Comment: Ah, the tabindex. Got it. Thank you. Will accept answer shortly. Thank you.

Comment: If it should only be focusable with the mouse but not be accessible with the tab key, a negative `tabindex` should be used.